# Remove tabs and spaces from start of each line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have strings containing code that can have whitespace in front of it (tabs & spaces):

```
        for foo in bar:
            foo += 1
            for i in range(0, foo):
                print(foo * foo)
```

Since whitespace defines scope in python, this won't compile. So what is a good way to remove whitespace from the start of each line ONLY if it occurs on every line in the string, giving the following result:

```
for foo in bar:
    foo += 1
    for i in range(0, foo):
        print(foo * foo)
```

The code is both generated and compiled in the same python program, so no other tools allowed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard library's `textwrap.dedent` function does exactly what you want.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what i'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
s = '''
        for foo in bar:
            foo += 1
            for i in range(0, foo):
                print(foo * foo)
    '''

lines = s.split('\n')[1:]  # remove the first empty line, just for this case
nrof_spaces = len(lines[0]) - len(lines[0].lstrip())

result = list()
for line in lines:
    result.append(line[nrof_spaces:])


print('\n'.join([''.join(line) for line in result]))
# Output
for foo in bar:
    foo += 1
    for i in range(0, foo):
        print(foo * foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read first line to string `a`, then :

```
lead_space=len(a) - len(a.lstrip()))
```

Now for each line `a` print :

```
print(a[lead_space:])
```

Comment: For instance, First line, `[8 spaces]for foo in bar:`; the nth line, `[4 spaces]if cond:`.

Comment: If your are considering such conditions too, then you may add the `lead_space` calculation to check if `new_lead_space` is lesser than the old `lead_space`. If yes then trim as per new variable else continue the old process.